# Relationship between Lie algebra representation and its semisimple quotient

Tags: lie-algebras

My question comes from the proof for proposition on page 127 of Fulton and Harris' *Representation Theory, a first course*. 
The proposition and its proof looks like this:

[image]

Also I cannot find any theorem relating to this one on Google, so I wonder if this proposition is even true.

Sorry for the formatting, I haven't figured out how to latex in post yet.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax references. Also, you might want to be more specific about what you don't understand.

Comment: Actually I put my comments in the image (which is the "1" you can click on)

Comment: Thanks for editing, Siong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}\g$ is a Lie algebra over a field $k$, then a one-dimensional representation is a Lie algebra map from
$\g$ to $k$ considered as a Lie algebra. This is a linear map,
but must preserve the Lie bracket. As the Lie bracket is zero on $k$
this means that it takes $[\g,\g]$ to zero. So a the one-dimensional
representations correspond to linear maps $\g\to k$ taking
$[\g,\g]$ to zero, equivalently to linear maps $\g/[\g,\g]\to k$.

In this example, one has $\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}\la:\text{Rad}(\g)\to k$
which vanishes on $\text{Rad}(\g)\cap [\g,\g]$. So we can extend
$\la$ to $\text{Rad}(\g)+[\g,\g]$ by setting
it to be zero on $[\g,\g]$. Then we can extend $\la$ to $\g$.